# Compare first and last post revision

Tags: revisions

I would like to know if I'm the only one who wishes to compare first and last post revision or better compare and two arbitrary revisions.

Even best would be being able to compare text in visual (Guthemberg) mode.

Is there a plugin to do such job? Would you suggest a strategy (api involved) to build one?

Comment: Have you used the built-in revisions comparison (e.g. `wp-admin/revision.php?from=123&to=124`) ? Please note that plugins recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't notice the "compare two revisions" button in "revisions"

[image]